# how to set on InterceptTouchEvent

Tags: android, scroll

I know that can use onInterceptTouchEvent on Override over a custom listview by extending. How Can set this event,or handle it.
Notice, I know setOnTouchListener can stop scrolling from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview)

but this can not help me.
can everyone help me?
thank you!

Comment: [go to this page for more information][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719787/custom-onintercepttouchevent-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as Android API level 19 (4.4 KitKat) there is not any handler method and interface to perform a hypothetical `setOnInterceptTouchEventListener()` or similar. So a boilerplate class extending `ListView` must be created in order to override `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.